# How do I reset state from a parent component in a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to trigger a modal to appear when there is an error in my form.

On my `app.js` file I have this handler function which is called when a field is blank:

```
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
  const [modalMessage, setModalMessage] = useState('');

  const alertModalHandler = () => {
    setModalShow(true);
    setModalMessage('User name field blank');
  }
```

These props are in turn sent to a modal component on Modal.js:

```
<AlertModal modalOpen={modalShow} modalText={modalMessage}/>
```

On Modal.js I have it so it uses `useEffect` to read the props and set an open/close state on the modal component.

```
const AlertModal = (props) => {

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {if (props.modalOpen) {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }}, [props.modalOpen])

  const handleClose = () => setIsOpen(false);

  return (
    <Modal show={isOpen} onHide={handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>Alert</Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>{props.modalText}</Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default AlertModal;
```

This works...but only once as I can't seem to reset `modalShow` from within `modal.js` when the modal is closed (when `isOpen` is false).

Would anyone know how I can do this?

My full App.js code is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import AddUserForm from './components/addUserForm';
import UserList from './components/userList';
import AlertModal from './components/modal';

function App() {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
  const [modalMessage, setModalMessage] = useState('');

  const addPersonHandler = (nameValue, ageValue) => {
    setUsers(prevUsers => {
      const updatedUsers = [...prevUsers];
      updatedUsers.unshift({ name: nameValue, age: ageValue });
      return updatedUsers;
    });
  };

  const alertModalHandler = () => {
    setModalShow(true);
    setModalMessage('User name field blank');
  }

  let content = (
    <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>No users found. Maybe add one?</p>
  );

  if (users.length > 0) {
    content = (
      <UserList items={users} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <AddUserForm onAddPerson={addPersonHandler} fireAlertModal={alertModalHandler}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            {content}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <AlertModal modalOpen={modalShow} modalText={modalMessage}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **App.js**, pass as props `setModalShow` to `AlertModal` like so :

```
<AlertModal modalOpen={modalShow} modalText={modalMessage} setModalShow={setModalShow}/>
```

Then in **AlertModal.js** (notice I simplified the code, for what you want to do, you don't need that `state` and `useEffect`) :

```js
const AlertModal = (props) => {

  return (
    <Modal show={props.modalOpen} onHide={()=> props.setModalShow(false)}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>Alert</Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>{props.modalText}</Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default AlertModal;
```

Comment: Yep, I thought this might be the way to do it. My only question is: isn't it a bit strange to separate the modal's logic (ie, when it closes) from the modal component?

Comment: I see your concern but, in this case, it makes perfectly sens that the consumer of `AlertModal` controls when it should open or close. And if you think differently, the logic of AlertModal is actually in it, it is to define how it will be consumed.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create a derived state from props, instead pass a callback from parent to child and maintain the state in the parent.

**App**

```
const alertModalHandler = () => {
  setModalShow(true);
  setModalMessage("User name field blank");
};

const handleModalClose = () => setModalShow(false);
```

Pass `handleModalClose` as handleClose prop to `AlertModal` component

```
<AlertModal modalOpen={modalShow} modalText={modalMessage} handleClose={handleModalClose}/>
```

**AlertModal**

```
const AlertModal = (props) => {
  return (
    <Modal show={props.modalShow} onHide={props.handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>Alert</Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>{props.modalText}</Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```